# SIGABRT error when using pushViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, pushviewcontroller, sigabrt

I am not sure why I am getting a SIGABRT error when I go to do the pushViewController. I have mpCustomFoodController as a IBOUTLET and have a viewController inside of my nib file and a file that is waiting to receive this but then it fails on this call every time.

```
 -(IBAction)createNewCustomFood:(id)sender{
    [self cancelButtonColorChange:sender];
    self.title = @"Cancel";

   mpCustomFoodController = [[MPCustomFood alloc]initWithNibName:@"MPCustomFood" bundle:nil];
   //this is where the error occurs once is calls this
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:mpCustomFoodController animated:YES];
   //this will be calling the new view
```

}

Comment: We need more information. `SIGABRT`s don't just happen; there's always an exception message that accompanies the crash. At least run a `bt` in your debugger so you can see the stack trace that lead to the error. If I had to guess, I'd say you either aren't using the correct nib name, or your File's Owner object has a non-existent outlet that's being assigned to.

Comment: #0  0x9a460c5a in __kill ()
#1  0x9a460c4c in kill$UNIX2003 ()
#2  0x9a4f35a5 in raise ()
#3  0x9a5096e4 in abort ()
#4  0x9a485b1b in _Unwind_Resume ()
#5  0x0121ae39 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#6  0x0121accb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#7  0x021d0879 in GSEventRunModal ()
#8  0x021d093e in GSEventRun ()
#9  0x00586a9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#10 0x00001c5d in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffece4) at /Users/rcrowell88/Desktop/VitabotApp/main.m:15
#11 0x00001bd5 in start ()
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c

Comment: I am not getting any exception message other then Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"

Comment: Set up an Objective-C Exception Breakpoint that breaks "On Throw". What you have there is a stack trace from the exception handling code.

Comment: #0  -[MealPlan createNewCustomFood:] (self=0x801cc00, _cmd=0x4c48e, sender=0x6870ab0) at /Users/rcrowell88/Desktop/VitabotApp/Classes/MealPlan.m:923
#1  0x012e5ec9 in -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] ()
#2  0x005895c2 in -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] ()
#3  0x0058955a in -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] ()
#4  0x0062eb76 in -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] ()
#5  0x0062f03f in -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] ()

Comment: #6  0x0062e2fe in -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] ()
#7  0x005aea30 in -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] ()
#8  0x005aec56 in -[UIWindow sendEvent:] ()
#9  0x00595384 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#10 0x00588aa9 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#11 0x021d1fa9 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#12 0x012b81c5 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()#13 0x0121d022 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#14 0x0121b90a in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#15 0x0121adb4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#16 0x0121accb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()

Comment: #17 0x021d0879 in GSEventRunModal ()
#18 0x021d093e in GSEventRun ()
#19 0x00586a9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#20 0x00001c5d in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffece4) at /Users/rcrowell88/Desktop/VitabotApp/main.m:15
#21 0x00001bd5 in start ()

Comment: Could you put your first comment as an answer and add that the fix has to be somewhere in the nib file not connecting the view properly to the file owner. I want you to put it because you had most of the answer and steered me in the right direction and deserve the credit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say you either aren't using the correct nib name, or your File's Owner object has a non-existent outlet that's being assigned to. Also, if you've replaced the main view in the nib or changed the class of its controller, the `view` outlet may be unassigned.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions given above.. it did not help me. **Finally i have to delete the nib and recreate it again, that solved my problem**.